# Umbraco Accessing Author Email

Tags: umbraco

I am trying to output the node's creator or author email via Razor.

I notice Umbraco has a pagefield built in for "creatorName" and I have tried to use this to find the user, and then access the email, but I'm having no luck. I've had a look at the Member and Membership APIs but most of the examples are outdated or expired and I am using v6.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for this please? (or is it even possible?)

Answer (score 0):

Note: users and members are different, and have a different API.
You probably want something like:

```
@{ var u = new User(currentPage.CreatorID); }
@u.Email;
```

Note: This will query the database for the user data. 
This is for 4.x but I Think 6.x is the same. (or at least backwards compatible)